# Can I Create an Image Object without using Storyboard and without dragging the Image View to storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11

Can I Create an Image Object without using Storyboard and without dragging the Image View to storyboard?
I want to show an image after the user click on a button. 
I am wondering if I can show an image without adding the UIImage to Storyboard. I prefer to do this with coding. The image is just an example. I want to learn how to do this with all objects. For example Text View, Images, Labels, etc.

Comment: Of course you can. Have you googled how to do it? Ray wenderlich site is an excellent resource. Another one is _let's build that app_ (the main focus on that site is UI generated via code).

Comment: Thank you @MauricioChirino, I found the answer and I posted the answer here as well. Sorry I am beginner in swift programming and I was very tired of adding everything from object explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/create-uiimage-and-uiimageview-programmatically/

Here is the code and the image in case someone have the same question:
[image]

Here if I click on Technology, It will show another picture and hide other elements.